# install.packages() from .Rprofile cannot find function "install.packages"

Tags: r, rprofile

my testing `.Rprofile`:

```
message("~/.Rprofile starting")

options(repos="https://cran.microsoft.com/")
if (!require("data.table")) install.packages("data.table")

message("~/.Rprofile ending")
```

works if I start with `R --vanilla` and then `source("~/.Rprofile")`, but not with a standard startup `R`, in which case the automatic sourcing of `~/.Rprofile` gives me

```
~/.Rprofile starting
Loading required package: data.table
Error: could not find function "install.packages"
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘data.table’
>
```

is there something (a library) that needs to be loaded first, that is usually loaded only after `.Rprofile` is executed (otherwise)?

I tried to debug this through `.libPaths()`, but lost it after I could not figure out where `.lib.loc` comes from in the function.  there must be some specific startup functioning related to the embedding of the .Rprofile somewhere, which defines .lib.loc and does some more stuff.

Comment: When interactive, R normally loads `utils`, but not when non-interactive as with Rscript or similar. Either use `library(utils)` or prepend with `utils::`.

Comment: I think the detailed answer to what you are trying to ham-first here is that _within the startup sequence_ when `~/.Rprofiel` is loaded tbe packages such as `utils` are not yet loaded so you probably need an explicit `utils::install.packages()`.

Comment: @r2evans: Try `Rscript -e 'search()'`.  The `utils` package gets loaded but I think later than Ivo needs it here.