# "Error: could not find function "install.packages"" when opening RStudio

Tags: r

This error appears in the console when I open RStudio and whenever I try to install a package such as **lme4**:

```
Installing 'lme4' ...

Installing package into 'C:/Users/dipie/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
lme4 1.1-31 1.1-32              TRUE

installing the source package 'lme4'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-32.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2946012 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

Error: could not find function "install.packages"
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:\Users\dipie\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpisNJ44\downloaded_packages'
```

I am using the latest versions of R and RStudio.

Comment: Do you have a .Rprofile file somewhere with `install.packages()` in it? If yes, try removing that line.

Comment: Check in your Tools -> Global Options that "Restore .Rdatainto workspace is unchecked

Comment: @dandrews, I unchecked the box but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @nrennie I found some .Rprofile files but they didn't contain that line. could there be some of these files hidden? I've tried to uninstall both R and R studio and I still get the same problem

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578170/install-packages-from-rprofile-cannot-find-function-install-packages. (add `library(utils)`)